# Ошибка на реальном устройстве после установки PNG изображения как фоновый рисунок

Tags: android, background, android-imageview

Существует проблема на реальном устройстве на эмуляторе таких проблем нет, ниже представлен код из xml файла по вызову изображения

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/untitledmin"/>
```

Читал уже другие вопросы но к сожалению ответа так и не нашёл при запуске вылетает такой свод ошибок

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cyhrazeetranslator/com.example.cyhrazeetranslator.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2477)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1345)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5452)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:762)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>           at com.example.cyhrazeetranslator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2370)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2477) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1345) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5452) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:762) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) 
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>           at com.example.cyhrazeetranslator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) 
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2370) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2477) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1345) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5452) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:762) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) 
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>           at com.example.cyhrazeetranslator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) 
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2370) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2477) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1345) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5452) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:762) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) 
>        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.cyhrazeetranslator:drawable/untitled" (7f060065) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060065 a=-1 r=0x7f060065}
>           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2602)
>           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
>           at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
>           at android.view.View.(View.java:3955)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:575)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:571)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:567)
>           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.(ConstraintLayout.java:575)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>           at com.example.cyhrazeetranslator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) 
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2370) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2477) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1345) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5452) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:762) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)

Следовал советам уменьшал фото на специлизированных сайтах, прописывал в манифесте

> android:largeHeap="true"
>   и ошибка осталась той же самой, ниже прикрепляю файл манифеста

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.cyhrazeetranslator">

    <application
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Какие могут быть пути решения?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была связана с разрешением изображения, только с 512*512 мне удалось поставить на фон